# Mvc: Exclude id from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, global-asax

I have the next foreach in my cshtml page, it allows to me iterate in each Model item

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="date">
        @item.pubDate
    </div>
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Details", new { action = "Details", controller = "News", id = item.id, title = item.title })">
        <img src="some route" alt="some alt" />                 
    </a>
}
```

so now it's working fine and each element inside foreach loop has an url with something like

```
http://something.com/News/Details/1/first-title
http://something.com/News/Details/2/second-title
```

It's possible create urls with something like

```
http://something.com/News/Details/first-title
http://something.com/News/Details/second-title
```

but i can still sending id parameter to my controller ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsTitleRoute",
    url: "News/Details/{id}/{title}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "News", 
        action = "Details", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        title = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
);
```

In your controller declare the details method like this, with the two parameters as optional:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string title="")
{
}
```

That route configuration and `Details` method will work for:

- http://something.com/News/Details/
- http://something.com/News/Details/1
- http://something.com/News/Details/first-title
- http://something.com/News/Details/1/first-title

Comment: and whati i should do in my controller for the id parameter ?, i need both title and id, but only display title in my url ... it's not working for me.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I changed how the route is configured. If you need both id and parameter then you need to pass it. Otherwise how can your site know what `id` to use if it has not received it?

Comment: ok you're right i thought it was possible send the id with some "behind" way only displaying title in url, it's not definitely possible what i'm trying to do ? :(

Comment: Well, say you put the `id` on a hidden field and do a `GET` request  submitting the form the id will still be appended on the URL. I have not tried hiding parameters from the querystring and I believe it's not possible. Unless there's some magical way of doing it.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the `title` property for `id` parameter.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Details",
              new { action = "Details", controller = "News", id = item.title})
```

Then set type of `id` parameter as string in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
```

Or you can create custom route like in von-v's answer. Just make sure it's above the default route.